# How to use a variable in switch statement

Tags: switch-statement, autohotkey

getting an error on "switch %direction%" - this line contains an unrecognized action.
why is it wrong?

```
myFunction(direction)
{
   switch %direction%
   {
      case "left":
      break
      case "right":
      break
   }
   return
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Switch requires Version 1.1.31+

---

"Break" is not used in AHK switch statements. ([Documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Switch.htm))

> The first statement of each case may be below Case or on the same line, following the colon. Each case implicitly ends at the next Case/Default or the closing brace. Unlike the switch statement found in some other languages, there is no implicit fall-through and Break is not used (except to break out of an enclosing loop).

This should work:

```
myFunction(direction)
{
   switch direction
   {
      case "left": MsgBox "LEFT"      
      case "right": MsgBox "RIGHT"      
   }
   return
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, i just copy it to a new seperate file and try to run, it gives an error at line 3: line: switch direction. error: this line doesnt contain a recognized action :/

Comment: in fact even i copy an example from AHK manual, it still gives the same error ::

Comment: installed the latest version, and it works now :: sorry guys, ill flag as right corrections. thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using Version [v1.1.31+] and bind your function to a key?

Comment: updated to the latest ver. now. yes, using it on key down `While GetKeyState("a","P"){}`. Simulating mouse moves on key press.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what language are you using but could you try this:

```
myFunction(direction)
{
   switch direction
   {
      case "left":
      break
      case "right":
      break
   }
   return
```

Comment: its for AHK script. `switch direction` gives me the same error